# Unable to allocate/reallocate pointer element of struct passed as pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

So, I am trying to devise a function (`incr`) that operates on a structure that is passed as a pointer. The structure (`ss`) is composed of (`ss.a`) one pointer to array of dim. 2, and (`ss.b`) a pointer to pointer to another array of dim. 2. The dimensions of both "arrays" (in the first "level") is correlated and stored in `ss.n`. The lenght of the pointer pointed by ss.b is of an arbitrary size that is stored in another member of the structure, but that is not causing me trouble (yet).

Sample code is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ss {
    int n;
    int (*a)[2];
    short (**b)[2];
};

// the manipulation function
void incr(struct ss* s)
{
    int j;
    
    s->n++;
    printf("Incrementing (s.n=%d)...\n", s->n);
    s->a = realloc(s->a, s->n*sizeof(*s->a));
    s->b = realloc(s->b, s->n*sizeof(*s->b));
    s->b[s->n] = calloc(s->n, sizeof(**s->b));
    
    s->a[s->n-1][0] = -s->n;
    s->a[s->n-1][1] = +s->n;
    for (j=0; j<s->a[s->n][1]; j++) {
        s->b[s->n][j][0] = j;
        s->b[s->n][j][1] = -2*j;
    }
}

// This is just for printing the contents of the struct
void prn(struct ss s)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("prn struct/n=%d\n", s.n);
    for (i=0; i<s.n; i++) {
        printf("%d [%d/%d]: ", i, s.a[i][0], s.a[i][1]);
        for (j=0; j<s.a[i][1]; j++) 
            printf("%d/%d , ", s.b[i][j][0], s.b[i][j][1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct ss s;
    s.n = 0;
    s.a = NULL;
    s.b = NULL;
    

    incr(&s); prn(s);
    incr(&s); prn(s);
    incr(&s); prn(s);
}
```

I got the segfault error when trying to access memory at `ss.b[...][...]` in the function `prn`, but sure the problem comes at the time of allocation of memory in `ss.b`. I can work the allocation of `ss.a`, but got stucked with the allocation of `ss.b`.

Expected output should be something like:

```
Incrementing (s.n=1)...
prn struct/n=1
0 [-1/1]: 1/2, 

Incrementing (s.n=2)...
prn struct/n=2
0 [-1/1]: 1/2, 
1 [-2/2]: 1/2, 1/2, 

Incrementing (s.n=3)...
prn struct/n=3
0 [-1/1]: 1/2, 
1 [-2/2]: 1/2, 1/2, 
2 [-3/3]: 1/2, 1/2, 1/2,
```

What is that I am doing wrong? To be honest, the passing of the structure as a pointer and using the `->` syntax kind of troubles me. The complete code should manipulate the lengths of `ss.a` and `ss.b` but I hope if you help me with this I will be able to manage that.

Thanks in advance for any help  :)

Comment: What is going on with `short (**b)[2]`? Why this masochism? Just make yourself a 1D array of the correct size, then use offsets to find the entries you need. Write an accessor/mutator function if needed. When you allocate memory like this, you're creating a single structure that's strewn about over the heap. It's not efficient at all.

Comment: You reallocated with length `s->n` but then do `s->b[s->n] = calloc(s->n, sizeof(**s->b));` but `s->b[s->n]` is out of range.

Comment: @tadman I appreciate your comment, and mostly agree. Maybe change to something like that in a final version, but since I am stuck with this I'd like to solve it even if it is for the sake of learning.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's right; and the example is working. However not on the original code though! Guess there is something else.

Kindly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but at the same time I do not envy you having to work with code that's like `s->b[s->n] = calloc(s->n, sizeof(**s->b))` where it's bordering on something that makes Perl look readable.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why you'd ever use a pointer to array `int (*a)[2];` is that you actually have a 2D array of dimensions `[x][2]` but wants to simplify the array access. `short (**b)[2];` however, doesn't make sense as a struct member in any sensible scenario I can think of. So drop the pointer-to-pointer - in addition to making everything obfuscated, it also makes the code slower.

Generally it's not wrong to use pointers to array like this, but they make the code needlessly complex and unreadable. You could consider doing something like this instead:

```
struct ss {
    int n;
    int* a;
    short* b;
};
```

And then let these point at 2D arrays/3D arrays etc but cast to the suitable array pointer only when you have actual use for it:

```c
short(*arr)[y][z] = (short(*)[y][z]) s->b;

for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
{
  for(int j=0; j<y; j++)
  {
    for(int k=0; k<z; k++)
    {
      arr[i][j][k] = something;
    }
  }
}
```

This is a well-defined cast and now we only have one single cryptic line instead of making the whole program unreadable. And the cast/temporary pointer variable costs nothing in terms of performance.

Then your realloc calls could be written along the lines of:

```c
int* tmp_a = realloc(s->a, sizeof(int[s->n][2]));
if(tmp_a==NULL) { /* error handling */ }
s->a = tmp_a;

int x = something_meaningful; // consider making a dedicated struct member for this
short* tmp_b = realloc(s->b, sizeof(short[x][s->n][2]));
if(tmp_b==NULL) { /* error handling */ }
s->b = tmp_b;

// no need for calloc here now - instead memset to zero if needed
```

---

Minor stuff:

- As noted in comments, `s->b[s->n]` was an array out of bounds bug.
- `struct ss s = {0};` is guaranteed to set all members to zero or make them null pointers.
- All variables/members and  functions in this program would benefit from more meaningful names.
- > The lenght of the pointer pointed by ss.b is of an arbitrary size that is stored in another member of the structure

  This is a bad idea, as noted in my realloc code. You should create a dedicated named member to hold this dimension.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot foresee what the dimensions of b are gonna be. Thosea are stored in a[i] such that b[i] has a[i] x 2 members ( b[i] -> b[ 0 : a[i] - 1 ][ 0:1 ] ). Also, increasing the size of any b[ i ] can happen at any moment of calling the function.

However, I can see now that I can use the already functional code to store the memory in this sort of "reallocation per call" and once it's done, rearrange all the memory in the fashion you suggest. Performance at the point of calling this function is not a concern, thoug it will be later in the workflow.